# Smoothing groups issue

Tags: modeling, export, normals

I'm using blender 3.1.0 and im trying to export an object via FBX to 3d max along with its smoothing groups. And this always USED to be possible from what I remember. Here is the usual process.

1. Create a cube
   [image]
2. Set shading to smooth

[image]

3. In edit mode mark edges as sharp

[image]

4. In object dataproperties, turn on autosmoothing and set the angle to 60 degrees.

[image]
[image]

Looks good.

5. Export thru FBX (using normals only) I also tried edges

[image]

6. Import in max (check if smoothing-groups import is checked in FBX settings) and voila, no smoothing group assigned at all.
   [image]

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1):

If rely on setting a specific angle to get your split normals then marking the edges sharp is not entirely necessary. If you want only the edges you marked sharp to be split then you would set the autosmooth degrees to 180. If you set this setting in Max:

[image: degrees for smoothing groups]

and this one in Blender:

[image: degrees for autosmooth in blender]

to the same degree value, then it will have the same result as if they shared the same "smoothing groups".

AFAIK, the concept of smoothing groups is a Max-Specific concept, and can't be transferred between different programs in itself. But if you split the normals one way or another it should transfer to the model between softwares.

I might be wrong, but it seems to be the case.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and explanation. I could have sworn it used to work before but maybe in newer blender released it stopped working. Shame.